# Question on topology

Tags: general-topology

Given two sets $X$ and $Y$. suppose we can endow each set with two different topologies $\tau_X, \tau'_X$ and $\tau_Y, \tau'_Y$.

Is there a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ which is continuous w.r.t the topologies $\tau_X,\tau_Y$ and not continuous w.r.t two $\tau'_X$ , $\tau'_Y$ ?

Comment: @user32415 what is meant by their graphs being continuous other than the function itself being continuous?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show some work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, $\tau_X$ be a trivial topology on $\mathbb{R}$, $\tau_X'$ be a discrete topology, and $\tau_Y=\tau_Y'=standard\ topology$. This means that the same non-constant function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ **is continuous at every point** in case of $(X, \tau_X')$ and $(Y,\tau_Y')$, and **is discontinuous at every point** if the case is $(X, \tau_X)\rightarrow (Y,\tau_Y)$. The conculsion can be derived from the theorem "$f:(X,\tau_X)\rightarrow(Y,\tau_Y)$ is continuous iff $U \in \tau_Y \implies f^{-1}(U)=V\in\tau_X$".

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you see that, if both $\tau_Y^{'} \subseteq \tau_Y$ and $\tau_X \subseteq \tau_X^{'}$, then every $(\tau_X,\tau_Y)$-continuous $f$ **must** also be $(\tau_X^{'},\tau_Y^{'})$-continuous, because "there are less '$Y$-opens' to *test (inverse images) for, against more* '$X$-opens'"?

Conversely, if one 'adds opens' to the codomain and 'loses opens' in the domain of $f$, that is, in case $\tau_X^{'} \subseteq \tau_X$ and $\tau_Y \subseteq \tau_Y^{'}$, then chances are some $f$'s will "stop being"/"no longer be" continuous (specially if they're surjective)

Everything ends up depending on comparability (continence or not) between the topologies (and so, to some extent, on the cardinalities of $X$ and $Y$). There may well be sharper results on the lattice of (pairs of) topologies. I have no idea, so let's hope someone more knowledgeable comes by and say something about it. But I hope this rather vague/sketchy paragraphs [the language is all deliberate] convey to you that the question is rather broad and that there are *many* possible outcomes

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.